# Checking a string if it is palindrome or not using pointer

Tags: c, loops, pointers, c-strings, palindrome

What does the bold part stand for in this code?  I've managed to fulfill most of the template (given by my teacher as assignment), can't find the reason behind that bold part.

I could use the strlen part before it appeared, I know one can still write the code without strlen at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strlen(char *str)
{
    int c = 0;
    while (str[c] != '\0')
    {
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}

int isPalindrome(char *str)
{
    char *ptr1 = str;
    char *ptr2 = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    while (ptr2 > ptr1)
    {
        if (tolower(*ptr1) != tolower(*ptr2))
        {
            return (0);
        }
        ptr1++;

        ptr2--;
    }
    return (1);
}
/**
            This function will
                -return 1 if the given string is Palindrome,
                -return 0 if the given string is not Palindrome.
        */

**int n = strlen(str);
// Write your code here**
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "ABCCBA ABCCBA"; //your input
    if (isPalindrome(str))
    {
        printf("%s is a palindrome", str);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s is not a palindrome", str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Making something bold inside code does not work and spoils the syntax. Please [edit] to otherwise point out the relevant part while keeping the syntax.

Comment: The point of `int n = strlen(str);` is to count the length of the string and store it in a new variable called `n`... the point of `// Write your code here` is so you know where to write your code... was that the question?

Comment: Don't reimplement `strlen`. Instead, `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: @Sri      "         **int n = strlen(str);
                         // Write your code here**    "   that was it--- the sterlen() part

Answer (score 1):

The teacher hinted that using the length of the zero-terminated input string will be needed. They stored that useful value inside a variable.

If you are required to use the code provided by the teacher, then move all your code AFTER that line and within your code replace the `strlen(str)` with `n`.

```
int isPalindrome(char *str)
{
        /**
            This function will
                -return 1 if the given string is Palindrome,
                -return 0 if the given string is not Palindrome.
        */

    int n = strlen(str);
    // Write your code here

    char *ptr1 = str;
    char *ptr2 = str + n - 1;
    while (ptr2 > ptr1)
    {
        if (tolower(*ptr1) != tolower(*ptr2))
        {
            return (0);
        }
        ptr1++;

        ptr2--;
    }
    return (1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the function template starts from the declaration of the variable `n` that gets the size of the passed string.

```
int isPalindrome(char *str)
{
    /**
        This function will
            -return 1 if the given string is Palindrome,
            -return 0 if the given string is not Palindrome.
    */
    int n = strlen(str);
    // Write your code here*
}
```

But you ignored this declaration and used the expression `strlen( str )` in this declaration

```
char *ptr2 = str + strlen(str) - 1;
```

instead of writing for example

```
int n = strlen(str);
//...
char *ptr2 = str + n - 1;
```

In any case the assignment looks not very well. For example this declaration

```
char *ptr2 = str + strlen(str) - 1;
```

can invoke undefined behavior when the passed string is empty.

The functions' parameters should be declared with the qualifier `const` because  passed strings as arguments are not changed in the functions.

The argument of the standard function `tolower` must be converted to the type `unsigned char`.

The functions could look the following way

```
size_t strlen( const char *str )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( str[n] ) ++n;

    return n;
}

int isPalindrome( const char *str )
{
    const char *ptr1 = str;
    const char *ptr2 = str + strlen( str );

    if ( ptr1 != ptr2 )
    {
        while ( ptr1 < --ptr2 && 
                tolower( ( unsigned char )*ptr1 ) == tolower( ( unsigned char )*ptr2 ) ) 
        {
            ++ptr1;
        }           
    }

    return !( ptr1 < ptr2 );
}
```

Also if the function strlen also must use pointers then it can look the following way

```
size_t strlen( const char *str )
{
    const char *p = str;

    while ( *p ) ++p;

    return p - str;
}
```

Here is a demonstration how your functions should look.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t strlen( const char *str )
{
    const char *p = str;

    while ( *p ) ++p;

    return p - str;
}

int isPalindrome( const char *str )
{
    const char *ptr1 = str;
    const char *ptr2 = str + strlen( str );

    if ( ptr1 != ptr2 )
    {
        while ( ptr1 < --ptr2 && 
                tolower( ( unsigned char )*ptr1 ) == tolower( ( unsigned char )*ptr2 ) ) 
        {
            ++ptr1;
        }           
    }

    return !( ptr1 < ptr2 );
}


int main(void) 
{
    char *str = "ABCCBA ABCCBA"; //your input

    if ( isPalindrome( str ) )
    {
        printf("\"%s\" is a palindrome\n", str);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\"%s\" is not a palindrome\n", str);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"ABCCBA ABCCBA" is a palindrome
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `isPalindrome` without any knowledge about pointers.
I prefer to use indices instead of pointers, look at the next example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int strLen(const char *str)
{
    int n = 0;
    while(str[n]) { ++n; }
    return n;
}

int isPalindrome(const char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = strLen(str) - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        if (str[i++] != str[j--]) { return 0; }
    }
    return 1;    
}

int main() {
    assert(isPalindrome(""));
    assert(isPalindrome("a"));
    assert(isPalindrome("aa"));
    assert(isPalindrome("aba"));
    assert(!isPalindrome("ab"));
    assert(!isPalindrome("aab"));
}
```

Comment: for loop was enough,,,

Comment: @Tarek Dakhran The assignment requires to use pointers instead of the subscript operator.